# Number of integer solutions by generating functions method

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm stuck in the middle of a problem and not sure where to go next.  The original problem is:

Find the number of integer solutions to the equation

$$2x + 3y + 4z + w + s + t = n$$   with $$0 \le w \le 2$$    $$2 \le s \le 5$$  $$0 \le t \le 3$$

Now I was able to create my generating functions equations to get my overall equation to this:

$$ G(x) = (\frac{1}{1-x^2})(\frac{1}{1-x^3}) (\frac{1}{1-x^4})(1+x+x^2)(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x+x^2+x^3)  $$

Which with the help of the finite geometric series and some cancelling I was able to simplify down to:

$$ G(x) = (\frac{1}{1-x^2})(\frac{x^2}{1}) (\frac{1}{(1-x)^3})(\frac{1-x^4}{1}) $$

But now I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit:  With the extra step of simplification

$$ G(x) = (\frac{x^2}{1}) (\frac{1}{(1-x)^3})(\frac{1+x^2}{1}) $$

Comment: Presumably $x,y,z$ are **nonnegative** integers?

Comment: Yes they all are

Comment: It would be better not to reuse $x$ between the equation and your generating function.  Also if you use \left( and \right) in your $\LaTeX$ the parentheses expand to be large enough to enclose everything inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can factor $1-x^2$ and $1-x^4$.

Comment: I tried that but it only took me to an equally stuck situation so I just went back a step

Comment: ... and then use partial fractions.

Answer (score 2):

You end up with:
\begin{align}
[x^n] G(x) 
  &= [x^n] \frac{x^2 + x^4}{(1 - x)^3} \\
  &= [x^{n - 2}] (1 - x)^{-3} + [x^{n - 4}] (1 - x)^{-3} \\
  &= \binom{-3}{n - 2} (-1)^{n - 2} + \binom{-3}{n - 4} (-1)^{n - 4} \\
  &= \binom{n - 2 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} + \binom{n - 4 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} \\
  &= \frac{n (n - 1)}{2} + \frac{(n - 2) (n - 3)}{2} \\
  &= n^2 - 3 n + 3
\end{align}